# Alexa Skills: Lambda function to read contents from a file in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa Skill that tries to read the contents from a file stored in S3. The test event for the Lambda function for Alexa Start Session is successful. I understand that there is something wrong with my CompletedMyIntentHandler but I can't quite seem to figure it out. Any help on it is much appreciated. The lambda function takes help from https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/blob/master/aws/Amazon-S3/read/. Find my Lambda function below;

```
   const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');     
     // 1. Text strings =====================================================================================================
        //    Modify these strings and messages to change the behavior of your Lambda function

        const helpOutput = 'You can demonstrate the S3 Storage read capability by saying "Hello".';
        const helpReprompt = 'Try saying "Hello World".';


        var myBucket = 'jailalita';      // replace with your own bucket name!
        var myObject = 'hello.txt';          // replace with your own file name!


        // 2. Intent Handlers =============================================

        const CompletedMyIntentHandler = {
          canHandle(handlerInput) {
            const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
            return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'MyIntent';
          },
          handle(handlerInput) {
            console.log('My Intent - handle');

            const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
            const speechOutput = MyIntent();
            return responseBuilder
            .speak(speechOutput)
            .getResponse();
          },
        };

        const HelpHandler = {
          canHandle(handlerInput) {
            const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
            return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
          },
          handle(handlerInput) {
            const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
            return responseBuilder
              .speak(helpOutput)
              .reprompt(helpReprompt)
              .getResponse();
          },
        };

        const CancelStopHandler = {
          canHandle(handlerInput) {
            const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
            return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && (request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent' || request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
          },
          handle(handlerInput) {
            const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
            const speechOutput = 'Okay, talk to you later! ';

            return responseBuilder
              .speak(speechOutput)
              .withShouldEndSession(true)
              .getResponse();
          },
        };

        const SessionEndedHandler = {
          canHandle(handlerInput) {
            const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
            return request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
          },
          handle(handlerInput) {
            console.log(`Session ended with reason: ${handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.reason}`);
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
          },
        };

        const ErrorHandler = {
          canHandle() {
            return true;
          },
          handle(handlerInput, error) {
            const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;

            console.log(`Original Request was: ${JSON.stringify(request, null, 2)}`);
            console.log(`Error handled: ${error}`);

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
              .speak('Sorry, I can not understand the command.  Please say again.')
              .reprompt('Sorry, I can not understand the command.  Please say again.')
              .getResponse();
          },
        };


        // 3. Helper Function  =================================================================================================

        function MyIntent() {

                var myParams = {
                    Bucket: myBucket,
                    Key: myObject
                };

                S3read(myParams,  myResult => {
                        console.log("sent     : " + JSON.stringify(myParams));
                        console.log("received : " + myResult);

                       var speech = this.response.speak('The S 3 file says, ' + myResult );
                       return speech;

                    }
                );

            }

        function S3read(params, callback) {
            // call AWS S3
            var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
            var s3 = new AWS.S3();

            s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
                if(err) { console.log(err, err.stack); }
                else {

                    var fileText = data.Body.toString();  // this is the complete file contents

                    callback(fileText);
                }
            });
        }


        // 4. Exports handler function and setup ===================================================

        const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();
        exports.handler = skillBuilder
          .addRequestHandlers(
            //LaunchRequestHandler,
              CompletedMyIntentHandler,
            HelpHandler,
            CancelStopHandler,
            SessionEndedHandler,
            )
            .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
              .lambda();
```

**JSON Input**

```
{
        "version": "1.0",
        "session": {
            "new": true,
            "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.e6f74d95-8d55-4aac-ade0-dd4ff4ed4f04",
            "application": {
                "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.5edd47bc-525d-4ef4-9b6e-a83a7e79744f"
            },
            "user": {
                "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AF4SLRK5TC4SDSHL7LGK2IB6SMXCPGS7Y6YKYLPDGWRE7CA3K6MCKVVUW2OFMVCWJFXZDQBSYY5Z2RXZWQAJLDCMR3SXYCVA7ZARDRNQXA3TXBM4ILP77FKNOO4MCVPLWHIXW3QNZCRYPDQ7CCBP6QT7GMTBMQX2BVCNS22SZL4MC6WB7GDS44XN2DKGJQBMGIDQ3O7RBYD6GAI"
            }
        },
        "context": {
            "System": {
                "application": {
                    "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.5edd47bc-525d-4ef4-9b6e-a83a7e79744f"
                },
                "user": {
                    "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AF4SLRK5TC4SDSHL7LGK2IB6SMXCPGS7Y6YKYLPDGWRE7CA3K6MCKVVUW2OFMVCWJFXZDQBSYY5Z2RXZWQAJLDCMR3SXYCVA7ZARDRNQXA3TXBM4ILP77FKNOO4MCVPLWHIXW3QNZCRYPDQ7CCBP6QT7GMTBMQX2BVCNS22SZL4MC6WB7GDS44XN2DKGJQBMGIDQ3O7RBYD6GAI"
                },
                "device": {
                    "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AETD2DDUWNTWA5BNNDFHCRT26SLOZUTZUFJ5P3OEQGDCWWDSFWPKNONGMT4KZAJPUB6ZRD3YVCDEVFAGPLXHVP6XESWS6BKEYZHZRXT25QNK2RTFNUG4PKD347P5DAWE2H4WQLGTQVLNQ5JNFGHFUSUC3X7Q",
                    "supportedInterfaces": {}
                },
                "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
                "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.Fc-aAcaf4qTgf489cQsZ44KTq-yZ-xMJCBenq9DbpppkMgSscF0NodGYTK967AcGblwqOFqcwIC1PvGmISER9oDH5TIhKF1kLsTimRHRKsttElRl7FIEvki-sKLD4VTeStTKM-w5laBm6urAzlCXpJySU-InVH5_qE0M5LHnLZRrE_qy7EmIq2vsrq2Cekve-gQ3Y3ImW3_0b7ikg6gwO6si-O0IxXO6hxS5sTuQH4f4aRybHVO3jflHD7g7pGPFzfkpc_tg6KFkhFv6CMvkx25A2u7iO7vVQpMHdj-_2ZM0ZmO9JuP-v7ydKYT_1IDjfpZKfvgIGyYsNfCPDY5F2Q"
            }
        },
        "request": {
            "type": "LaunchRequest",
            "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.12ef23e3-a7e5-48a4-90f9-de9c253f72b9",
            "timestamp": "2018-07-02T05:39:24Z",
            "locale": "en-US",
            "shouldLinkResultBeReturned": false
        }
    }
```

**JSON Output**

```
    {
        "body": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "response": {
                "outputSpeech": {
                    "type": "SSML",
                    "ssml": "<speak>Sorry, I can not understand the command.  Please say again.</speak>"
                },
                "reprompt": {
                    "outputSpeech": {
                        "type": "SSML",
                        "ssml": "<speak>Sorry, I can not understand the command.  Please say again.</speak>"
                    }
                },
                "shouldEndSession": false
            },
            "sessionAttributes": {},
            "userAgent": "ask-node/2.0.0 Node/v8.10.0"
        }
    }
```

**JSON Editor**

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "hello world",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "MyIntent",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "hello"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: The Alexa Start Session test case for the lambda function returns the Error Handler output. Ideally it should be returning the contents from the hello.txt file stored in the S3 bucket.

Comment: Can you provide the JSON schema of your skill? And what is printed in the logs?

Comment: @NikhilWagh, I have added the requested to the original question itself. Kindly find there.

Comment: No. This is the input. I'm asking about JSON schema. You can find the schema in the **Build** section of your Alexa skill builder. Look for **JSON Editor**.

Comment: @NikhilWagh, I have added the Interaction Model to initial code

Comment: You need to add more samples to your intent `MyIntent`. "Hello" should not be a sample utterance to your intent. It should be something like a command, like "*tell me the weather forecast*", or "*tell me a joke*".

Answer (score 0):

You can't build your response and return inside the S3Read function as it's an async call to an external service. You need to wait for that call using async/await and once you get a value then craft the response and return.